# Power Query M: "Group" based on running total

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a dataset that has total sales and unit price. I'd like to add a new column that flags each group based on each $100 worth of sales. Some orders have already been fulfilled, so I'd like to ignore these.

Is it possible to create a running total, and then add a column with a label that shows every group of orders with a limit of 100 per order?

[image]